# Does EasyNetQ support nack?

Tags: rabbitmq, easynetq

What I'm really trying to do is leave the message on the queue in the case where it is rejected by the current consumer. In RabbitMQ I could send a NACK to accomplish this. Is NACK supported in EasyNetQ? Is there another way to achieve the behavior I'm looking for?

**Update**: not a lot of responses, so I'm wondering how people are generally handling the lack of NACK in EasyNetQ. Not having the equivalent of `basic.reject` limits consumers to "I can always process every message" scenarios. I suppose consumers could throw a specific "rejected" exception to cause EasyNetQ to dequeue the message to the error queue, and I could requeue messages with those errors. Anyone else have other workarounds in place?

Answer (score 4):

I used EasyNetQ for almost a year, but no matter how we tweaked it (amongst other things added our own implementation of `IConsumerErrorStrategy`) I never really got it to work the way I wanted. The fact that it is single threaded gave us some unexpected behaviour (sometimes deadlocks) when performing `RequestAsync` while in a `SubscribeAsync` handler.

The solution for us was to move from EasyNetQ. After working with the official RabbitMq Client for a while, I spent a few days writing a *super thin* client on top of that. It is influenced by EasyNetQ and supports most of the concepts that EasyNetQ has. However, I added some neat features like pluggable message contexts. I think that the Nack feature of `IAdvancedMessageContext` that I just added can be something for you:

```
var client = service.GetService<IBusClient<AdvancedMessageContext>>();
client.RespondAsync<BasicRequest, BasicResponse>((req, ctx) =>
{
  ctx?.Nack(); // the context implements IAdvancedMessageContext.
  return Task.FromResult<BasicResponse>(null);
}, cfg => cfg.WithNoAck(false));
```

If you're interested you can read more about it at the [Github page](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit#advanced-concepts) (especially the [`NackTests.cs`](https://github.com/pardahlman/RawRabbit/blob/master/src/RawRabbit.IntegrationTests/Features/NackingTests.cs)).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can change the behavior by implementing your own IConsumerErrorStrategy:

https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/master/Source/EasyNetQ/Consumer/DefaultConsumerErrorStrategy.cs

But if you need that kind of control you might consider just using the RabbitMQ client directly?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks like the handler in the error strategy is invoked when a consumer throws, so I'd have to throw an exception that I can recognize as being a "rejection" by the consumer and then nack. If there isn't a better way then I might just handle it myself by re-queuing the original message. Not really a nack, but it could be enough for my purposes.

Comment: Update: I tried just requeueing the message but it has a side effect. The send occurs on the same thread as the handler for the original message, which is still unacked. This means that a connection failure after the send will requeue the original message, resulting in two duplicate messages on the queue. An edge case, but possible, and I don't like it. So I may got with the exception approach (see my update in the question).

Comment: Yes, and this is inevitable, because using this approach you will implement the smantics "at least once"

Comment: @BitMask777 ideally you want to model your messages to be idempotent, there are many situations in which messages can be delivered multiple times (retries, connection errors etc).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to handle failures. You can NACK a message, but that means it sits at the head of the queue. Great, but then it means that you could end up with a bunch of messages that are truthfully unable to be processed, and you will be unable to actually process real messages.

The solution that I have always used when using RabbitMQ is to utilize the default error handling of EasyNetQ, and have a separate application to resend messages. That is, when an exception is captured in RabbitMQ, it routes the message to a queue called "EasyNetQ_Default_Error_Queue". You are able to override this name and have different queues go to different error queues, but for now let's stick with the default. You can then have a Windows Service/Azure Worker role reading these messages, and working out what to do. That may include having a "RetryCount" on your message envelope/wrapper to make sure that it only loops around so many times. All in all, it's going to be a bit of work.

What you are finding, is what many people run into when using RabbitMQ/EasyNetQ. She's pretty raw.